# Django forms and registration: insert data to other tables

Tags: django, forms, authentication, django-forms

In my app, I've got 2 types of users: Student and Teacher. I want to store additonal information about each of them in separate table.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nr_indeksu = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

Let's assume i want to register user as student - In that case, i need to expand User registration form, so it will contain fields from Group and Student model, and during registration i want to insert Student.nr_indeksu with Student.user_id(FK) into student table, and Group.name into User_Groups.

I've created StudentForm by using Meta Class and rendered it in template in the same form where UserCreationForm is, but i don't know how to handle saving into database, because UserCreationForm creates user_id that it's supposed to go into Student mode. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Solved it by making the model look a little different:

```
class Student(User):
nr_indeksu = models.BigIntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.user)
```

This way, when you define the Django form, all needed fields will be rendered for this model. This is because you are saying **The student is a user** , as opossed to the former **the student has a user**

The form could look like:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Edit:
Use a similar approach for teacher model.
If you want to avoid the rendering of some fields, use the fields attribute in the Meta class.

Second Edit:
If you want to preserve the validations and checks of the User form, the form should also inherit from UserCreationForm.

Comment: Hey it seems to work, but it's just brand new form that inherits it's fields from User right? Because i cannot call fields like 'password1' or 'password2', and 'password' return a TextField as Default. What should i do to inherit password and other safety methods from UserCreationForm?

Comment: I've actualy found the answer to my own comment and i think it's worth pointing out - StudentForm should inherit from UserCreationForm by StudentForm(UserCreationForm)

Comment: Nice! Sorry for taking so long, I was out eating :P